# How do I remove restrictions from a PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Good afteroon.
I'm currently trying to add some pdf files into 1 using PdfReader. One of those files has a "Copy Content restriction" on it's properties. How can I eliminate this?

Code:

```
foreach (string file in filesOrden)
{
    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file))
    {
        pdf.AddDocument(pdfReader);
        PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;                                 
    }
}
```

I tried using `pdfReader.RemoveUsageRights();` inside the `using` block, but it doesn't enter this block of code.

Comment: string file in filesOrden is to read all the files in a folder. Im using iText version 5.5.13.2

Comment: I'm fairly new to this lenguage so I don't know how to change a version of iTextsharp andI don't know how to shell out to qpdf or similar to rebuild the troublesome pdf file without restrictions

Comment: *"but it doesn't enter this block of code."* - if your `filesOrden` is not empty, it must enter that block or throw some kind of exception. (Well, or exit altogether or be stuck in some endless loop or lock.) What happens in your case exactly?

Comment: It's throws and exception: Uknown encryption type R = 6

Answer (score 0):

This restriction has most likely been applied intentionally by the author of the document.

Ask the author for a non restricted version.

Comment: Max Wyss, yeah that's what I feared, I thought maybe there's a way to automatically remove the restrictions.